# MySql result to csv

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to save a mysql query to csv. I have searched and found various options. This option seemed like nice and clean code, but not working

I get an error

## 1045 - Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

```
SELECT *
FROM clients
INTO OUTFILE 'mytest.csv'
```

When I remove `INTO OUTFILE 'mytest.csv'` it works fine

(SQL code simplified)

Comment: maybe add something like 'c:/.../mytest.txt' ?

Comment: @MarcElBichon. Thank for the comment. Still the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is

```
SELECT Your_Column_Name
    FROM Your_Table_Name
    INTO OUTFILE 'Filename.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

That is permission error for "unidimec" in localhost.check the user privilege for "unidimec" and give privilege from mysql root user.

Comment: The user has full privilege

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'unidimec'@'localhost';                then give                                                                                                FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to grant permission to mysql user for generate file.

Login with SSH **(if you have dedicated server, otherwise you have to contact your web hosting support)**

login with root in mysql by below command

```
mysql -u root -p[password]
```

After login in mysql interface grant file permission for this user

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'unidimec'@'localhost';
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation of "INTO OUTFILE" very carefully:

> The SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE statement is intended primarily to let you very quickly dump a table to a text file on the server machine. If you want to create the resulting file on some other host than the server host, you normally cannot use SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE since there is no way to write a path to the file relative to the server host's file system.
>
> However, if the MySQL client software is installed on the remote machine, you can instead use a client command such as mysql -e "SELECT ..." > file_name to generate the file on the client host.
>
> It is also possible to create the resulting file on a different host other than the server host, if the location of the file on the remote host can be accessed using a network-mapped path on the server's file system. In this case, the presence of mysql (or some other MySQL client program) is not required on the target host.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html